# Is it Possible to use MobileFirst app Quality Assurance without Bluemix MQA Service?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, mobilefirst-qa

I learned  about [MobileFirst Quality Assurance](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/quality-assurance/)

I believe that MQA Bluemix service is awesome. But, we want to use MobileFirst Quality Assurance without Bluemix MQA Service. As per the link above, Bluemix ID and Bluemix MQA service are required to use Mobile Quality Assurance service for a mobile application. Is it possible to use just MobileFirst Quality Assurance without Bluemix MQA Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the previous release of MobileFirst Quality Assurance: cannot guarantee it will work: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.install.doc/topics/t_instproduct.html

MQA is moving to a Bluemix model. I believe you will also need to purchase it.